# Why is the pressure value of an ideal gas for a fixed density and constant temperature of gas more than that of the same real gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, molecular-dynamics

I solved a question-

Under what pressure will carbon dioxide have the density 500g/l at the temperature 300K? Carry out calculations for ideal and Van der Waals.

On solving for pressure, I get
For ideal - 279 atm
For real - 80 atm

Why is this so? Why is there a huge difference?

Answer (score 0):

In most gases, at "reasonable" pressure, molecules attract each other on average. That's what the "a" term stands for in the VdW equation of state:

$P=\frac{nRT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}$

You may see this as molecules hitting "less hard" the walls of the container because other molecules "hold them back".